# jQuery.load not working with a combined string

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

Im trying to use the jQuery.load function to get a partial view from my controller using the following code:

```
var url = '/Home/DropDownCity?state=' + $('#dropDownState:first-child').text();
console.log(url);

$("#containerCity").load(url);
```

If the code is ran as written above, it does not work. Nothing is loaded and i get no errors. If i explicitly define "state", it will work:

```
var url = '/Home/DropDownCity?state=Ohio';
```

In both cases, `console.log(url)` logs exactly the same thing: `/Home/DropDOwnCity?state=Ohio`

Why does it work when i define state in the string, but not when i try to combine the string with the text from the element even though the both seem to output the same string? How do i make it work the way i want it to?

Comment: How about `$('#dropDownState').text().trim()`? But why would you use `:first-child` on one element? Does it make sense?

Comment: Try  `var state = $('#dropDownState:first-child').text();`, then `var url = '/Home/DropDownCity?state=' + encodeURIComponent(state)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that `:first-child` is supposed to further filter a collection of possibly more than one. When you always have 1 element, as is the case for an ID selector, you do not need that, AND when the element you're applying `:first-child` to happens not to be the first child of it's parent, you will alway get an empty collection:

So I would say use:

```
$('#dropDownState').text().trim();
```

Unless you're interested in the children of this element and you want the first child:

```
$('#dropDownState').children().filter(':first-child').text().trim();
```

And you want to be sure there're no spaces around the `text()` by using `.trim()`. You may event go a step further and make sure there're only allowed characters by using a regular expression.

```
$('#dropDownState').text().replace(/([a-z ]*)/,'$1').replace(/ /g, '+');
```